# Looking for a clean way to convert a string list to valid List<long> in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm hoping to find a better way (maybe with a nice [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) expression) to convert a string list like "41,42x,43" to a list of valid long's.  The below code works, but it just feels ugly.

```
string addressBookEntryIds = "41,42x,43";
var ids = addressBookEntryIds.Split(new[] {',', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var addressBookEntryIdList =new List<long>();
foreach (var rec in ids)
{
    long val;
    if (Int64.TryParse(rec, out val))
    {
        addressBookEntryIdList.Add(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string addressBookEntryIds = "41,42x,43";

Func<string, long?> safeParse = (s) => {
            long val;
            if (Int64.TryParse(s, out val))
            {
                return val;
            }
            return null;    
};


var longs = (from s in addressBookEntryIds.Split(new[] {',', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            let cand = safeParse(s)
            where cand.HasValue
            select cand.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: I tested this in Linqpad; I do something similar with unsafe input in my code, but my source data actually comes from SQL.  I won't say this is prettier in any way--I think your original code is just fine.  It is concise, clear, and to the point.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression:

```
var list = Regex.Matches(@"41,42x,43", @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => Convert.ToInt64(x.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: That may or may not work depending on the form the entries.  42x43 would create two entries, not zero as it should based on the reference implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another LINQ version:

```
String addressBookEntryIds = "41,42x,43";
Int64 val = 0;

addressBookEntryIds
  .Split(new[] {',', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Where(id => Int64.TryParse(id, out val))
  .Select(id => val)
  .ToList()
```

If you prefer a query expression, you can use:

```
from id in addressBookEntryIds.Split(new[] {',', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
where Int64.TryParse(id, out val)
select val
```

Comment: This LINQ version is by far the neatest IMO

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's a LINQ version, but it's not really any less ugly!

```
string addressBookEntryIds = "41,42x,43";
var ids = addressBookEntryIds.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Int64 converted;    // Working value used within the select
IEnumerable<Int64> values = ids.Select(x => new
{
    Success = Int64.TryParse(x, out converted),
    Value = converted
}).Where(x => x.Success)
  .Select(x => x.Value);
```

The difference between this solution and anderson's is that `TryParse` is only called once per entry.

Answer (score 0):

Just a derivation of your code, quite redundant (uses TryParse and then Parse again), but I think it works:

```
addressBookEntryIds.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Where(id => 
                   {
                       long val;
                       return Int64.TryParse(id, out val);
                   })
                   .Select(id => Int64.Parse(id));
```